# What is a good way, and a good language, to create a cap on recursive functions?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have heard that recursion have the potential to overflow or memory leak due to every function call requiring some memory use. And I figured even if I wouldn't overflow the memory I might still like to cap the number of function calls. So using Javascript and throw I made this factorial function but I wonder if there is a more native way of doing it, or if there are programming languages that are more suited for this type of work?. Is there some solution that improves upon the linear memory use of such algorithms?

```
const CAPSIZE = 5
function factorial_req(a) {
  if( a == 1 ){
    factorial_req.stack_slack = CAPSIZE
    return 1
  }
  else if( factorial_req.stack_slack == 0 ){
    throw 'stack cap'
  }
  else {
    factorial_req.stack_slack--
    return a * factorial_req(a-1)
  }
}
factorial.stack_slack = CAPSIZE
function factorial(a) {
  try {
    return factorial_req(a)
  }
  catch(err) {
    if( err == 'stack cap' )
      return 0 // 0 == flase
    else
      throw err
  }
}
// test
console.log( `5! = ${factorial(5)} , !3 = ${factorial(3)} and !9 == 0 is ${factorial(9) == 0} and !9 == false is ${factorial(9) == false} while !99999999 == true is ${factorial(99999999) == true}`)
```

Comment: The point of a recursive function is to keep going till you meet a certain condition. You also need to call the same function within itself which your second function doesn't satisfy

Comment: Normally, tail call optimisation (TCO) is what helps with recursive algorithms not overflowing. In languages/environments without TCO support, you can use manually implement it using a [trampoline](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/trampolining-a-practical-guide-for-awesome-java-developers-4b657d9c3076). In short you convert your recursive function to return a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) and call it as `trampoline(recursiveFn())` then the trampoline handles the stack calls. `throw` is definitely not the best way to handle recursion.

Comment: "*has the potential to overflow or memory leak*" - and so does a simple loop. Btw notice that throwing an exception at a certain depth is no different than a stack overflow exception by the runtime.

Comment: Just write this as a loop if you're concerned about memory or performance, or just about any other metric. I'm not sure there's any point to adding a cap to recursion. The runtime already throws when you recurse too deeply; why not use that? Leaking memory and running out of memory are two different things. Leaking memory only happens when you lose all references to a resource, which isn't happening here.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you wrote uses linear space. You can't implement your algorithm in less than linear space. The key is to use a tail-recursive algorithm. The correct implementation of tail recursion does *not* result in linear space usage.

Consider a basic implementation of the factorial function, written in pseudocode

```
factorial(n) = 1 if n == 0
               n * factorial(n - 1) otherwise
```

which is basically the definition of the factorial function. Then the evaluation of `factorial(3)` proceeds as follows:

`factorial(3)`
`3 * factorial(2)`
`3 * (2 * factorial(1))`
`3 * (2 * (1 * (factorial(0)))`
`3 * (2 * (1 * 1))`
`3 * (2 * 1)`
`3 * 2`
`6`

Note that it is the very nature of the algorithm which requires linear space.

Now consider a different implementation of factorial. We want to write a helper function called `factorial_helper` which satisfies the property `factorial_helper(acc, n) = acc * n!`. This gives us the following algorithm:

```
factorial(n) = factorial_helper(1, n)

factorial_helper(acc, n) = acc if n == 0
                           factorial_helper(acc * n, n - 1) otherwise
```

Now consider the evaluation of `factorial(3)`.

`factorial(3)`
`factorial_helper(1, 3)`
`factorial_helper(3, 2)`
`factorial_helper(6, 1)`
`factorial_helper(6, 0)`
`6`

Notice that the evaluation of `factorial(n)` uses constant space (assuming an integer takes up constant space) under the second implementation. This is because `factorial_helper` is tail-recursive. This means that whenever, in the computation of `factorial_helper(a, b)`, we make a recursive call, the result of that recursive call is exactly `factorial_helper(a, b)` (there's no extra processing). In other words, the recursive call in `factorial_helper` is, if it occurs, the "last thing `factorial_helper` does".

Unfortunately, JavaScript is currently not guaranteed to properly implement tail recursion. This makes it a rather unsuitable language for recursion generally.

It is always possible to implement recursive functions iteratively by switching to continuation passing style. Languages like Haskell make this very easy. For example, implementing factorial in Haskell looks like this:

```hs
factorial n = if n == 0 
              then 1
              else n * factorial (n - 1)
```

And in continuation passing style, this looks like

```hs
factorial n = if n == 0
              then return 1
              else (n *) <$> factorial (n - 1)
```

It's a very minor syntactic change, but factorial is now implemented using continuations and will thus not suffer from a stack overflow (although it still uses linear memory in `n`).